# How to stop a running python script by Ansible?

Tags: python, ansible

In the `node1` host, there is a Python script `py_script.py`:

```
import time

while True:

    print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))

    time.sleep(1)
```

then in my `ansible` host, I can use the ansible to start the script:

```
ansible node1 -m shell -a 'python py_script.py &'
```

then it will start running.

but how can I stop it?

Comment: This is a weird way to use Ansible in combination with Python.

Why not let a cronjob start the Python script. And why doesn't the python script stops on it's own? Simply set an exit statement in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should have `systemd` manage your script or have some other kind of service.

If you do not want that, you can use `pkill` to kill this script:
`pkill -f "python py_script.py"`
This will kill all processes with the command `python py_script.py`.

You can do `ansible node1 -m shell -a 'pkill -f "python py_script.py"'`